# ES6: How to get values from nested JS object/Array of objects, without using Switch-case statement

Tags: ecmascript-6, webdriver-io

ES6: How to get values from nested JS object/Array of objects, without using Switch-case statement, for retrieving locator values.

But we don't want to use `switch-case` statement.

Kindly advise on functional programming alternative

```
let selector = null;
browser.timeoutsImplicitWait(3000);
const LOCATORS = {
topFilterIcon: 'AXY',
tabHeadings: {
    IOS_SELCT: {
        ValueTab: 'bla',
        UnitsTab: 'bla2',
        PriceTab: 'bla3'
    },
    ANDROID_SELECT: {
        ValueTab: 'abc1',
        UnitsTab: 'abc3',
        PriceTab: 'abc4'
    }
},
```

};

Code which we want to replace with functional programming is as below:

```
    switch (heading.toString().toLowerCase()) {
case 'value':
    selector = browser.isIOS ? LOCATORS.tabHeadings.IOS_SELCT.ValueTab : LOCATORS.tabHeadings.ANDROID_SELECT.ValueTab;
    break;
case 'units':
    selector = browser.isIOS ? LOCATORS.tabHeadings.IOS_SELCT.UnitsTab : LOCATORS.tabHeadings.ANDROID_SELECT.UnitsTab;
    break;
case 'price':
    selector = browser.isIOS ? LOCATORS.tabHeadings.IOS_SELCT.PriceTab : LOCATORS.tabHeadings.ANDROID_SELECT.PriceTab;
    break;
default:
    throw new Error('\n Error: Incorrect value received on Market Section ');
}
```

Kindly advise thanks

Comment: We'll be fine to convert above Nested Object to Array of Objects / Map if necessary. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform the key to the corresponding key you want to get:

```
let key = heading.toString();
key = key[0].toUpperCase() + key.slice(1).toLowerCase() + "Tab"
const selector = LOCATORS.tabHeadings[browser.isIOS ? "IOS_SELCT" : "ANDROID_SELECT"][key];
if (selector === undefined) {
    throw new Error('\n Error: Incorrect value received on Market Section ');
}
```

Comment: Should I make the top level structure as Array of object?

Comment: I suppose you could, but it is not necessary.

Comment: Sorry for a side question, Could you please suggest some reading material on ES6 / JS ? for somebody switching into it from Java. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have no idea, but a little search gives [this](https://www.quora.com/How-should-a-java-programmer-learn-JavaScript-and-node-js/) and [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-textbook-tutorial-to-learn-JavaScript-for-a-Java-SE-desktop-developer). A nice way to learn quickly is to participate in some challenges, like codewars, and skill up that way.